# Java / Generics

Tags: java

I hava implemented a generic arraylist with

```
public Object[] toArray()
{           
    return elementData;
}
```

to be able to sort it later. When i try to get the elements out

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(10000);
    list.add(1000);
    list.add(100);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(1);

    Object[] a = list.toArray();

    for(Object o:a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

it prints "[Ljava.lang.Object;@2a139a55" and such things, however the runtime type must be Integer here, isn't it?

Comment: This is *not* generic. It is an `Object` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typo here:

```
for(Object o:a)
{
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

should be

```
for(Object o:a)
{
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

By the way, just calling `System.out.println(list);` is enough here.

Comment: Or, if this is not an example, and you really just want to print the array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: Btw, you can iterate over the list itself, no need to transform it into an array. Lists also have a "usable" `toString` method. `for(Object o: list){`

Comment: @Thilo what is wrong with my answer in the comments?